# How do I integrate logging in Python with actual text output?

Tags: python, logging

The intuitive way to do this would be to have a logging level that just always prints to any log file for actual program output. But there is no such level - the top level is logging.critical, which should correspond to a fatal error rather than the successful output of the program.

As far as I can tell, the only setting for system output is logging.info which actually has low priority. If I used it, then the log file would also contain exception warnings. What is the right way to get "program output" into a file using logger?

Comment: if your app is running under umbrella of another app and that another app use critical level logging than I think the right place to adjust logging  is that app. Impacting how the app logging behaves from your "subapp" is bad idea,

Comment: But what if my app is supposed to produce text on the screen or in a file? I just want to always produce that result without needing to use two different text output methods

Comment: is that a logs or result of program execution ?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to log just critical errors to screen and log everything to a file?  If yes, then that can be easily done.